# Equations of motions for 3D pendulum in SymPy

Tags: sympy, physics

does anybody have experience with obtaining equations of motions in sympy for 3D pendulum using sympy mechanics ? I tried to do it the easiest way as possible, but the resulting mass matrix has NaNs in it, does anybody know how to fix the problem ?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
from sympy import symbols, trigsimp, simplify
from sympy.physics.mechanics import Body, PinJoint, JointsMethod, ReferenceFrame, dynamicsymbols, mechanics_printing, mprint, SphericalJoint
mechanics_printing()

l, m, g = symbols('l m g')
q1, q2, q3 = dynamicsymbols('q1 q2 q3')
q1d, q2d, q3d = dynamicsymbols('q1 q2 q3', 1)
u1, u2, u3 = dynamicsymbols('u1 u2 u3')
u1d, u2d, u3d = dynamicsymbols('u1 u2 u3', 1)

ceiling = Body('C')
bob = Body('U', mass=m)
joint = SphericalJoint('P1', ceiling, bob, child_point=-l*bob.x, coordinates = [q1, q2, q3], speeds = [u1, u2, u3])

bob.apply_force(-ceiling.y*bob.mass*g)

method = JointsMethod(ceiling,joint)
method.form_eoms()
mm = method.mass_matrix_full
fo = method.forcing_full
mmi = simplify(mm).inv()
qudots = mmi*fo
mprint(simplify(qudots))
```

Comment: i will suggest you to check input values of l,g and mass for this system also  NaNs in the mass matrix can sometimes occur due to singularities in the system. Check if there are any constraints or singularities in your system that might be causing this issue. if did not solve  make sure that the force is correctly defined and aligned with the appropriate direction. then check  the simplify function from Sympy to simplify the expressions involved in the mass matrix calculation it help eliminate any unnecessary complexity that might be causing issues.

Comment: I suggest asking this question on GitHub rather than here: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/discussions

Comment: @OscarBenjamin thanks, didn't realize I could post my question there.

Comment: @Rainysidewalks I think everything should work, unsimplified mass matrix shows no NaNs. I'll try to play with it, maybe I'll figure it out, thanks for the answer anyway

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/discussions/25971